# Connection between Storm Topology and HBase in a server

Tags: hbase, apache-storm

I have HBase stored at docker in a server. I have created a Storm topology which contains HBaseBolt and I connected HBaseBolt as below code:

```
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    ...
    builder.setBolt("indexer", new HBaseBolt("webpage", mapper)).localOrShuffleGrouping("parse").withConfigKey(CONFIG_KEY);
    ...    
    return submit("crawl", conf, builder);
```

How do I pass connection parameters of HBase server to Topology?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.storm.hbase.bolt.HBaseBolt

In the topology config you can set the hbase config properties.

Comment: I have seen these examples, but I couldn't figure out how I pass the ip and port of server where hbase and its configuration file are stored.